# Egg mass on glass

Tags: species-identification, eggs

mid-April, East Texas
Can someone ID the egg mass deposited on our window? It's about the size of a fingerprint.

[image]

I may have to try again with photo- thanks for forbearance

Eggs are bright green, mass is oval in shape but each is round and linearly arranged. On glass.

Comment: Can you get a picture from the other side of the glass?

Comment: Mollusc or insect I suspect. Slug or snail  most likely.